# I am new to Scala. I used to work in pySpark. How I can convert these lines of code into scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

y_train = train_['country_destination']
train_user.drop(['country_destination', 'id'], axis=1, inplace=True)
x_train = train_df.values

label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoded_y_train = label_encoder.fit_transform(y_train)
```

In above mentioned code, I was trying to encode labels and features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so using the [`stringIndexer()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/ml-features.html#stringindexer)

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer

val df = spark.createDataFrame(
  Seq((0, "a"), (1, "b"), (2, "c"), (3, "a"), (4, "a"), (5, "c"))
).toDF("id", "category")

val indexer = new StringIndexer()
  .setInputCol("category")
  .setOutputCol("categoryIndex")

val indexed = indexer.fit(df).transform(df)
indexed.show()
```

Comment: This is working for me. Thanks